# get all values in cs(Referer)

Tags: python

I'm having an IIS server log file, as you know it has a field called cs(Referer).I want to get all values under this column?please help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt','r')
data = f.read()

import re

#print data

def find(pat,text):
        match = re.search(pat,text)
        if match: print match.group()
        else: print 'not found!'
```

Comment: How would we know that? Please give an example of the log file. I for one has never looked at an IIS log in my life!

Comment: #Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status                               
2012-11-27 23:59:59 W3SVC1 192.168.5.3 GET /online/scripts/keyboard.js - 443 - 175.157.83.133 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+rv:16.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/16.0 https://www.mysite.com/online/2/2/22001.aspx 200 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is as follows:

1. Find the "#Fields:" comment and find out the index of the columns
2. Skip comment lines that begin with "#"
3. Print the column we're interested in

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt','r')

columns = {}

for line in f.readlines():
    if line.startswith('#Fields:'):
        for index, substring in enumerate(line.split(' ')):
            columns[substring] = index
    elif line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    else:
        print line.split(' ')[columns['cs(User-Agent)']]
```

Comment: Do you understand all of the code or do you need further explanations?

Comment: I've renamed some variables to make it easier to understand. Basically enumerate() is what you use when you want to loop through a list and also you need to know which step you are at in the loop. It gives you the index of the loop and the item in the list, instead of just the item as a normal "for...in.." loop.

Comment: Again could you please tell me why you have put  [columns['cs(User-Agent)'] instead of putting cs(referer)?  Please consider I'm new to Python.

Comment: line.split(' ') will give me the columns in the file. I need to figure out which column corresponds to "cs(User-Agent)". The variable columns holds the mapping. So in your example "columns['cs(User-Agent)']" is 11. So "line.split(' ')[columns['cs(User-Agent)']]" becomes "line.split(' ')[11]". To understand you can try printing out the variable "columns" to see what it looks like.